# dovecot: doveconf: Fatal: execvp(/usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve) failed: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, email, dovecot

Настраиваю виртуальный почтовый сервер на `postfix`+`dovecot` c SASL, TLS.

Приём писем не работает, папки в vmail с доменом и именем не создаются, и при попытке подключить pop3-сервер к морде `gmail` выдаёт ошибку:

```
Сервер отказал в доступе по протоколу POP3 для данного имени пользователя и пароля.
    Ошибка сервера: "[SYS/TEMP] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information."
```

При этом в `/var/log/mail.err`

```
dovecot: doveconf: Fatal: execvp(/usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve) failed: Argument list too long
dovecot: config: Error: managesieve-login: dump-capability process returned 89
```

Только я вообще не понимаю что с этим `managesieve` делать и как его отлаживать?
Файлы `managesieve` и `managesieve-login` в `/usr/lib/dovecot` присутствуют, но что им не хватает мне не ясно.
Подскажите куда копать и в чём тут может быть дело?

**doveconf -nP**

```
# 2.2.27 (c0f36b0): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.16 (fed8554)
doveconf: Fatal: execvp(/usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve) failed: Argument list too long
doveconf: Error: managesieve-login: dump-capability process returned 89
# OS: Linux 4.8.13-1-default x86_64  
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = vmail
mail_home = /var/lib/vmail/%d/%n
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_uid = vmail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = scheme=ssha512 username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
  user = vmail
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_ca = </etc/path/to/ca.crt
ssl_cert = </etc/path/to/cert.crt
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_client_ca_file = </etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
ssl_key = </etc/path/to/key.key
ssl_options = no_compression
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
verbose_ssl = yes
```

Comment: во-первых, информация про postfix не нужна и лишь «засоряет эфир». у вас ведь не работает maa (mail access agent), а не mta (mail transfer agent).

Comment: во-вторых у вас maa жалуется на проблемы с managesieve. вероятно, там собака и зарыта

Comment: Разобрался с логами postfix-а и теперь в /var/log/mail.err
2016-12-20T14:51:05.307787+02:00 ilya dovecot: doveconf: Fatal: execvp(/usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve) failed: Argument list too long
2016-12-20T14:51:05.313636+02:00 ilya dovecot: config: Error: managesieve-login: dump-capability process returned 89
Только я не понимаю что это вообще такое и как это отлаживать.

Comment: 1. ещё раз повторяю: вам не mta (в качестве которого вы используете программу postfix) надо разбираться, а с maa (в качестве которого вы используете программу dovecot). 2. ещё раз повторю: всю информацию про mta из вопроса можно смело удалить — postfix не имеет к описанной ошибке никакого отношения. 3. приведённая в комментарии информация уже содержится и в вашем вопросе. 4. больше информации смотрите в логе maa.

Comment: ну и для начала я бы на вашем месте исключил все упоминания про сертификаты и шифрование из конфигурации maa. и тестировал бы не сторонними серверами, неизвестно как работающими, а с помощью mua (или, на крайний случай, telnet-ом).

Comment: 1 Я понял, что у меня не работает maa, но я до сих пор не понимаю почему. После включения логов постфикса у меня в них появились ошибки довекота, как бы странно это не звучало.
https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/ManageSieve/Configuration
2 Я не хочу, по крайней мере пока, этого делать.
3

Comment: Это руководство мне мало чем помогло. В настройках dovecot у меня ManageSieve вообще отключен, и даже включение его и изменение ограничивающих опций вообще никчему не приводят. Порт 4190 молчит, даже если его раскомментировать, да и не нужен мне ManageSieve вовсе. Расскоментирование опций дебага и трассировки Sieve тоже ничего не дала, тут уже я не знаю что делать.

Comment: execvp(/usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve) failed: Argument list too long
Не говорит мне вообще ни о чём, так как  не понятно какие аргументы он имеет ввиду. Я лично вообще никакие аргументы ему не передаю и он у меня вообще отключен. И не гуглится, точнее никакой полезной информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А дело было в этой строке.

```
ssl_client_ca_file = </etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
```

Точнее в линем символе `<` левой угловой скобки в начале пути, из-за которой в логах писалось чёрт знает что, даже отдалённо не связанной с SSL.
При этом сертификаты в опциях `ssl_key` `ssl_cert` `ssl_ca` указываются почему-то с ней, а именно этот сертификат в опции `ssl_client_ca_file` указывается без неё.
При этом `doveconf` не обнаруживает никакой синтаксической ошибки, а стрелки переводит на `managesieve` который тут вообще никаким боком не причастен.

https://dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2016-December/106549.html